# Reverse An object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I want to reverse an object in JavaScript. For Example:

Input: `obj ={'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three':3 }`

output: `obj ={'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one':1 }`

Is there any method in javascript or lodash?

Comment: You can't. Objects' keys aren't supposed to be ordered. Some browser do preserve insertion order but there's no reason to count on it. What are you using this for anyways?

Comment: What is your use case here? We might be able to suggest something for you.

Comment: As Andrew pointed out, the order you talk about does not exist. What you *can* do and probably mean is the way the object gets serialized (to Json) or printed out. You could overwrite the *.toString()* function of your object in order to print out its properties in an ordered way, for example.

Comment: If your object keys are `1/2/3` and the values are `one/two/three` then you can sort it in `asc` like that `var obj ={3:'three', 2:'two', 1:'one' }
console.log(Object.keys(obj));` though it's not your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

here is what you're looking for,

```js
function dict_reverse(obj) {
  new_obj= {}
  rev_obj = Object.keys(obj).reverse();
  rev_obj.forEach(function(i) { 
    new_obj[i] = obj[i];
  })
  return new_obj;
}


my_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three':3 }
rev = dict_reverse(my_dict)
console.log(rev)
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with others, the order of keys in object are not guaranteed. But if you are ok with it and you trust its in order of insertion, you can swap them by this function:

```js
reverseObj = (obj) =>{
    return Object.keys(obj).reverse().reduce((a,key,i)=>{
        a[key] = obj[key];
        return a;
    }, {})
};
const result = reverseObj({a: 'aaa', b:'bbb', c: 'ccc'})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this ?

```js
let obj ={'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three':3 };
let result = {}, stack = [];
for(property in obj){
 stack.push({'property' : property, 'value' : obj[property]})
}
for(let i=stack.length-1;i>=0;i--){
 result[stack[i].property] = stack[i].value; 
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Object.values(errors).reverse()
```

Comment: Code only answers may be correct but consider adding the why and how the code solves the problem to add context to the answer.

Comment: this does not result in the desired output. But instead would return `[3, 2, 1]`